# Google App maker drive picker folders

Tags: google-app-maker

In app maker driver picker is there a option to add files in folders and from app maker we are creating documents that should be added in the specified folder.

Files uploaded will be accessed by all the users in the application so is there an option to upload files in centralized drive location, or do we need to maintain a folder in some one's drive and all the users will upload files in that drive folder.

Can anyone suggest the possibilities to implement in app maker.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three basic strategies to implement this:

**[Team Drives - infeasible](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/drive/get-started-team-drive/)**

The best one but it is not supported by App Maker at this time.

**Service(robot) Account - infeasible**

Run your app under some service account and save/serve files on its behalf... this approach isn't supported by App Maker at this time.

**Personal Shared Folder**

The option suggested by topicstarter. Unfortunately, the only feasible solution at the moment. Just in case, here is a server-side code snippet how to add file to folder in Drive:

```js
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

folder.addFile(file);
```

Comment: This can be done.. but if we provide like this all users files will be updated in single user's drive right.

Comment: But it is not the correct implementation for collaborating document across all the users in the application

Comment: App Maker is still in EAP stage, so don't be so strict to it =)